# Deploy to google play new apps automation

Tags: android, deployment, automation, google-play, fastlane

I need to upload a public **new** android application to google play automatically.

I use Fastlane, but its **supply** functionality supports only update exists applications of google play.

I also read about create new applications by google play API on google docs:
https://developers.google.com/android/work/play/custom-app-api/get-started

but it is talking about private applications support only.
I believe that many white label companies implemented a thing like that, but really didn't find any helpful information.

Thanks for your answers.

Comment: From what I could find you still have of manually create app to start off with (after which you can, as you mentioned, use something like fastlane supply to publish/update meta-data/promote etc)

Comment: It's really disappointing. Apple approves uploading a new app through the API.  Google annoyed me.

Answer (score 0):

Just to give you a bit of background picture why allowing automatic creation of the app through an API is not a great idea.

- Most people don't need to create lots of apps. Those who do are often spammers (I'm not saying you are). Slowing down app creation and stopping them doing it automatically helps everyone.
- When you first create an app there are some legal steps which need a human to be involved. Your app also needs to get age/content ratings which requires answering a questionnaire. Again, having a human involved is helpful here, as you are taking legal responsibility for the answers.
- As described on the Google Play Policy Center, [apps are not allowed to be created by Wizards](https://play.google.com/about/spam-min-functionality/spam/wizard/) (automatic app creation programs). This helps keep app quality higher, which is good for users. Stopping automatic app creation via an API helps prevent people accidentally breaking this policy